Not able to install ubuntu kernal linux-image-6.5.0-1020-oem giving error Operation not permitted
When I am updating my ubuntu I am stuck on a kernal install and due to it no software in updating and installing on my system. When, I am running sudo apt upgrade error
When I am running apt --fix-broken install, I am getting this error -error
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-6.5.0-1020-oem_6.5.0-1020.21_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-1020-oem.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-6.5.0-1020-oem_6.5.0-1020.21_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I have tried every resolution but it is not working space is also there and also tried to changes boot folder permission but not resolved. please help

It must be sudo apt --fix-broken install

The sudo is crucial for the apt command.

Tried with sudo but didn't work. even the files(kernel version) it is installing are already installed.

Here is the solution that works for me:
Basically, Antivirus prevents the installation of the packages as my system has already one (McAfee agent).
First of all, I checked the status of the antivirus with the following commands if it is running or not:
# /opt/McAfee/ens/tp/init/mfetpd-control.sh status
# /opt/McAfee/ens/esp/init/mfeespd-control.sh status

If it is running then stop the services with these:
# /opt/McAfee/ens/tp/init/mfetpd-control.sh stop
# /opt/McAfee/ens/esp/init/mfeespd-control.sh stop

Then check the status again if it is stopped or not. If stopped then I started necessary updates and required installations by this:
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Finally, I started the antivirus again by these:
# /opt/McAfee/ens/esp/init/mfeespd-control.sh start
# /opt/McAfee/ens/tp/init/mfetpd-control.sh start

